# does removeAt remove the element as well as push the elements after forward one index or keep the index?

Tags: c++, vector

Does removeAt() in vector class in C++ remove the element as well as push the elements after forward one index or keep the index?

Comment: There is no `removeAt` method, which method do you really mean? Nevertheless, any such method will push the elements forward and invalidate all iterators starting from the erased element.